# Obtaining Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and have been stuck on this piece of code for a couple days.

```
select distinct Count( AGVGLST.AGVGLST_PIDM ) "Count_AGVGLST_PIDM",
       Count( (select distinct pidm
       from donor
       where donor.pidm = agvglst_pidm
       and donor.cfae_cat IN ('ALMB','ALMX')) ) "Cfae"
  from AGVGLST
 where AGVGLST.AGVGLST_DESG ='1125'
       and AGVGLST.AGVGLST_FISC_CODE ='2010'
       and not exists(select 'x'
       from agvglst b
       where b.agvglst_pidm = agvglst_pidm
       and b.agvglst_desg <> '1125'
       and b.agvglst_fisc_code = '2010')
```

I am trying to get counts for only this desgination '1125' so I need to reference it twice and for some reason I am getting zero counts when I know there are donors who donated to only that specific desgination. I am sure it is something stupid I am missing.

Comment: which rdbms please? sql server?

Comment: Also, you're counting these guys but who also didn't give anything for any other designation than 1125, so maybe that's the reason your count returns 0. It might clear things up to have some sample datas.

Comment: sql server.That is right I only want to count those who gave to 1125 and not anything else. I do have data where I know donors only gave to 1125 in fiscal year given. So I know 0 is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you run this query?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.AGVGLST_PIDM) "Count_AGVGLST_PIDM",
FROM AGVGLST a
WHERE 
    a.AGVGLST_DESG      = '1125'
AND a.AGVGLST_FISC_CODE = '2010'
AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 'x'
            FROM 
                agvglst b
            WHERE b.agvglst_pidm = a.agvglst_pidm
            AND b.agvglst_desg <> '1125'
            AND b.agvglst_fisc_code = '2010'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work by giving the other table an alias.

Comment: wait, I mean, I changed your query, there's a part missing. Don't you need the other count result in the select?

Answer (score 1):

```
   not exists(select 'x'
   from agvglst b
   where b.agvglst_pidm = agvglst_pidm
   and b.agvglst_desg <> '1125'
   and b.agvglst_fisc_code = '2010')
```

May be this is creating problems here. There can be donor whose designation is not '1125' but agvglst_fisc_code is '2010'. So, due to existance of records your Not exists is restricting '1125' to be counted.

Answer (score 0):

When something that should be simple starts getting too complicaed; it's time to backup and start over:

```
select 
  AGVGLST_DESG,
  coun(*) as "Count_AGVGLST_PIDM"
from AGVGLST
where AGVGLST_DESG = '1125'
group by 
  AGVGLST_DESG
```

Any additional filter-fields get added to the select list and the group by list, and then tothe where clause.